# What would be the qualities of an 'ideal' skimboarding surface material?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

**TL;DR:** Apparently it is ground effect which allows the board to skim across the surface so I am wondering what saturated surface material would allow the skimboard to travel the furthest?

---

**Detail:** 
Traditionally "flatland" skimboarding is done in the shallow water of a sandy shore but it can be done on other surfaces with sufficient water coverage such as [road and grass](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wXLZ19HNp_0).  There is [footage of one event](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gFoD25aZacs) in which the organisers appear to have used artificial grass over pond lining.

So I am wondering how surface roughness inhibits or encourages ground effect, e.g. is there a sweet spot between 'too rough' and 'too smooth'. 
 E.g. PTFE sheets vs fine sand vs artificial putting green grass.

I realise the complexities of hydrodynamics may make it impossible to give an answer without modelling or experimentation.

Comment: Do you have any evidence, even anecdotal, that any particular surface is faster or slower than any other?  It looks like water is minimising friction to me, and the surfaces are not relevant to the skimming. (Maybe to the running along, though.)

Comment: Well, I was reminded of how wind speed in a given location is affected by the 'surface roughness' of a landscape, e.g. vegetation, structures, etc. It is looked at when assessing suitability of sites for wind energy projects.  Though a smaller scale, I was wondering whether roughness would inhibit the formation of -- or, encourage the decay of -- the ground effect vortices in a similar fashion.

Also, the board loses momentum I would guess an uneven surface is going to cause surface contact and increased friction sooner than an even one.